# "В отсутствие" или "в отсутствии"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно:

> обвиняя себя в отсутств**ие** времени

или

> обвиняя себя в отсутств**ии** времени.

Comment: @Виталий sweet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Стоит различать по смыслу существительное отсутствие с предлогом в,поставленного в предложном падеже и имеющего окончание -и.
Напр.: ***В отсутствии(в чем?)*** Иванова на нашей встрече нет ничего необычного. 
Существительное "отсутствие" в форме винительного падежа с предлогом "в" может переходить в наречно-предложное сочетание "в отсутствие". Оно указывает на лицо, отсутствующее во время какого-либо действия, о котором говорится в предложении: В отсутствие (кого?) Ивана Петровича в отделе произошла смена кадров( В то время, когда его не было).  "В отсутствие" - имеет абсолютно то же самое значение, что и предлог "без" Напр.: Рассмотреть дело в отсутствие свидетелей( без свидетелей).
Следует также запомнить, что предлог ***"в отсутствие"*** употребляется только при ответе на вопрос ***"кого?"***.Ни в коем случае ***не "чего?"***
Поэтому правильно: Обвиняя себя ***в отсутствии времени.***
Отличить предлог от существительного с предлогом ***"в"*** не сложно. Трудность представляет оборот типа **"в его/мое отсутствие"**. По поводу этого оборота вот что пишет Грамма.ру.

> "Оборот типа "в его / моё отсутствие" употребляется в соответствии с традицией, установившейся в официально-деловой речи в первой половине 19 века. Как можно предполагать, свою роль здесь сыграло то обстоятельство, что грамматическая конструкция ***"предлог В + существительное в винительном падеже"*** способна выражать временное значение (ср. обороты: в старину, в дождь, в войну, в сессию и т.п.)".

Comment: "Следует также запомнить, что предлог "в отсутствие" употребляется только при ответе на вопрос "кого?".Ни в коем случае не "чего?" -- Серж, можете указать источник?

Comment: @М_Г, указать в ответе или просто дать вам ссылку?

Comment: Думаю, в ответе ее увидят все (комментарии не все читают)

Comment: @ М_Г, достаточно заглянуть в словарь. Думаю, ссылку на словарь на словарь давать не стоит.

Comment: "В отсутствие доказательств вины подсудимого суд оправдал его. — Поскольку нет доказательств вины подсудимого, суд оправдал его."

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/v-otsutstvie-v-otsutstvii.html

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае (если смысл в том, что отсутствие времени - вина) происходит обычное склонение (-и), но бывают внешне похожие случаи, когда нужна особая внимательность.
В присутствии присяжных и в отсутствие вышедшего судьи он принялся обвинять выступивших свидетелей в отсутствии чести и совести.
Здесь "при судье" т. н. оборот с непервообразным предлогом, когда падежи не действуют: "в отсутствие судьи" = "в ситуации отсутствия судьи" (в этом эквивалентном варианте, как и в случае "отсутствия чести" падежи действуют). С "присутствием" таких метаморфоз не присходит.

Answer (score 1):

В отсутствиИ. Существительное на -ИЕ. предложный падеж.

Answer (score 1):

Обвиняя себя **в отсутстви*Е*** времени, бездарно тратишь его (**нареч.** *"в отсутствие"* /чего?/ *"времени"* - винительный падеж).

Обвиняя себя в **отсутстви*И*** времени, признаёшь свою несобранность (**сущ.**  *"отсутствие"* в предложном падеже - /в чём?/ *"в отсутствии"*).