# "При отсутствии" или "при отсутствие", и вообще ПРИ?

Tags: орфография, окончания

*При отсутствии жалоб* или *при отсутствие жалоб?*

Полный текст: *при отсутстви(и/е) жалоб — записаться на прием к врачу.*

И вообще такая конструкция правильная? Или нужно "в случае отсутствия" или "в отсутствии"?

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически возможные конструкции:

a) при отсутстви**и** (предложный падеж),

б) в случае отсутствия (родительный падеж),

в) в отсутстви**е** (винительный падеж); для сравнения с похожим словом: в присутстви**и** (предложный падеж); вариант с предложным падежом "в отсутстви**и**" требует принципиально иного контекста (*в отсутствии жалоб нет ничего удивительного*).

Однако *стилистически* вариант "в отсутствие" не вполне сочетается с "жалобами". Он более характерен для ситуации отсутствия людей, например:

> В отсутствие главврача поликлиники его замещает заведующий Первым
>   отделением.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, *при отсутствии*, предложный падеж бесспорен, ударение соответствующее. Предлог при сам за себя говорит. Вы просто начали путаться, наверное, по аналогии с парой *вследствие - в следствии* (где первое предлог, второе - сущ. с предлогом). Хотя вариант *в отсутствие* тоже имеет место быть, но не в вашем случае, что уже сказано было тут: [вариант написания **в отсутствие**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: *при отсутстви**и**.* При чём? При отсутстви**и** (предложный падеж).

Конструкция вполне хороша: *при отсутствии жалоб — записаться на прием к врачу.* Тире заменяет слово "нужно". Если это не отдельная фраза а её конец, то тире не нужно, если на месте тире или перед ней стоят слова "нужно", "рекомендуется" или "рекомендуем" и др.

*"В случае отсутствия"* тоже сказать можно, но *"при отсутствии"* и короче, проще, и естественней звучит.

Answer (score 0):

```
При отсутстви(и/е) жалоб — записаться на прием к врачу. При "отсутствии" пишется с буквой И на конце, так как в словах, оканчивающихся на -ий, -ие, -ия в предложном падеже пишется на конце ИИ. Все конструкции "в случае отсутствия", "в отсутствии", "при отсутствии" имеют право на существование и используются в официально - деловом стиле.
 Про тире уже сказали. Я согласна, что это неполное предложение, и на месте пропуска одного их членов предложения может ставиться тире.
```