# В отсутствие или в отсутствии?

Tags: окончания

**В отсутствие данной информации, помочь нельзя...**

Правильное ли окончание употреблено в слове "отсутствие"?

Comment: Разница между "в отсутствие" и "в отсутствии" уже обсуждалась. См.: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Я задал дополнительный вопрос на эту тему: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432820/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be

Answer (score 3):

Предложение неясно по смыслу, его необходимо исправить, перестроить.

***В связи с отсутствием (из-за отсутствия) данной информации помочь (вам) нельзя (невозможно).***  (Вы имели в виду это?)

Ср.:

***В отсутствиИ данной информации виноват он.*** - Предложный падеж существительного ОТСУТСТВИЕ, окончание -И.

***Это было сделано в его отсутствиЕ.*** - Наречие В ОТСУТСТВИЕ, неизменяемое, на конце Е.

Comment: К вашему сведению: @Серж пишет: "Следует также запомнить, что предлог "в отсутствие" употребляется только при ответе на вопрос "кого?".Ни в коем случае не "чего?" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Серж писал о предлоге. С ним вполне можно согласиться. В данном же предложении употребление предлога "в отсутствие" невозможно.

Comment: Да, конечно. Я только хотел расставить в этой теме все точки над i

Comment: С интересом прочитала полезную информацию по Вашей ссылке. Такой комплексный подход к решению вопроса импонирует. Зачёт.

Answer (score -1):

**Окончание правильное** (винительный падеж). Буквальный смысл: *во время* отсутствия ("время" - в винительном падеже, ср. *в момент, в час, в день* чего-л.); общий смысл: *в ситуации отсутствия* (с временным  оттенком - "всегда, всякий раз, когда имеет место отсутствие"). **Запятая - лишняя**: конструкция "в отсутствие чего-л." здесь выступает как член простого предложения (обстоятельство условия).

> В отсутствие данной информации помочь нельзя...

Данное предложение в предполагаемом контексте ("вы просите помочь, но для этого нужна такая-то информация"; нет уверенности, что было задумано именно так) выражает смысл:  *Если/поскольку такой информации у вас нет, мы не сможем вам помочь...*

Comment: Окончание-то правильное, вот только фраза неграмотная. )