# Предлог «в отсутствие» употребляется только при ответе на вопрос "кого?"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Впервые встретил это утверждение в ответе Сержа, затем нашел и интернете.

*Запомните, что предлог «в отсутствие» употребляется только при ответе на вопрос «кого?» Ни в коем случае не «чего?» Именно поэтому словосочетания типа «в отсутствие ветра», «в отсутствие мнения», «в отсутствие электричества», «в отсутствие денег» и т.д. считаются некорректным. Такие слова «в присутствии» и «в отсутствие» употребляются только по отношению к людям. По отношению к неодушевленным предметам правильно говорить: «при наличии электричества», «при наличии ориентира», «при отсутствии денег», «при отсутствии мотива» и т.д.*
(http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-43243-kak-pisat-v-otsutstvii-ili-v-otsutstvie#ixzz4lIHMx76J)

Хотелось бы получить подтверждение и ссылку на надежный источник

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Розенталя и Лопатина (из тех книг, где это пока нашлось) приводится "кого", но прямых оговорок нет; в качестве противопоставления фигурирует только "(не "в отсутстви**и**")".
Во многих современных книгах на научные и юридические ("в отсутствие доказательств") темы употребление с "чего" встречается. Попадался такой текст даже в сборнике статей "Культура русской речи". Пример из старого источника:
*(Энциклопедический словарь Брокгауза и Ефрона)*

> Этот факт дал возможность Пастеру сделать широкое обобщение
>   относительно брожения: брожение есть жизнь **в отсутствие** воздуха.

В отсутствие более серьёзных источников остаётся сослаться на лояльное отношение к данной теме сайта "Грамота":
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%92%20%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%92%D0%98%D0%95&limitstart=0

Comment: Оно не "лояльное" отношение, оно императивное. И совершенно верное в данном случае.

Comment: В ответах на некоторые вопросы там содержатся оговорки, например: "в отсутствие" обычно указывает на лицо - мол, стилистически предложение из вопроса небезупречно; тем не менее, примеры предложений с "чего" не отвергаются как ошибочные, и даются ответы на сопутствующие вопросы. Поэтому "поголовно" твёрдой позиции отвечающих там не наблюдается.

Comment: Не вижу там "оговорок", указывающих именно  на ненормативность (даже слабую) сочетания с неодушевленным объектом. А выводить её из "обычно" - это как из "обычно я еду на трамвае" доказывать отсутствие в городе другого транспорта. Ладно, не суть. Гланое, что очевидно опровергают какой-либо запрет на подобное сочетание.

Comment: Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Предлог _в отсутствие_ употребляется с вопросом _кого?_ (не _чего?_). Поэтому _в отсутствие документов_ считается некорректным.

Answer (score 0):

М_Г, все очень просто. Надо разобраться с падежами и частями речи.
А по ссылке - просто очередной фейл от знатоков умозрительных формулировок.

В отсутствии (чего/кого) - в чем, в ком (предложный падеж, состояние)
В отсутствие (чего/кого) - во что, в кого (винительный падеж, направление)

В современном языке предлоги стали связываться с порождающим существительным. Отсюда вся путаница, включая и данную. Но на самом деле к дополнению в родительном падеже этот вопрос вообще никакого отношения не имеет. Он в обоих случаях родительный, и там - "чего/кого" никто не отменял.

Поэтому "в отсутствие кого/чего" - совершенно правомерный вариант.

"Возгорание произошло в отсутствие руководства на рабочем месте" (канцеляризм) - предлог.

"Причину возгорания видели в отсутствии руководства на рабочем месте" - существительное.

*Я, может, несколько поверхностно, но настолько нелепая исходная
формулировка, что даже не знаешь, на каком уровне разбирать. Если что - дополняю и поясняю.*

(+++++)

Я подумал, что тут, возможно, всё объясняется неверным понимание того факта, что "в отсутствие" - предлог, а "в отсутствии" - существительное с предлогом... Правда, все равно непонятно, как они вывели запрет на сочетаемость с неодушевленным дополнением...

Answer (score -1):

В Академическом орфографическом словаре предлог в отсутствие (кого)(при отсутствии). 
По поводу этого предлога. Ответ Граммы.ру.

Оборот типа «в его / моё отсутствие» употребляется в соответствии с традицией, установившейся в официально-деловой речи в первой половине 19 века. Как можно предполагать, свою роль здесь сыграло то обстоятельство, что грамматическая конструкция «предлог В + существительное в винительном падеже» способна выражать временное значение (ср. обороты: в старину, в дождь, в войну, в сессию и т.п.).